# whatsapp-web.js: is it possible to add a URL preview for WhatsApp message, like the web client do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, puppeteer, whatsapp

Using the following code, I can successfully send text message to a phone number via WhatsApp using `curl` command:

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const client = new Client({
    puppeteer: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    }
});

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    console.log('QR Code received, scan it with your phone.');
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();

app.post('/send-message', async (req, res) => {
    const { number, text } = req.body;

    if (!number || !text) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing number or text' });
    }

    try {
        await client.sendMessage(`${number}@c.us`, text, { linkPreview: true });

        console.log(`Message sent to ${number}: ${text}`);
        res.status(200).json({ success: 'Message sent' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending message' });
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Then with `curl`, I can run

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"number": "1234567890", "text": "text http://stackoverflow.com "}'
```

But even with `linkPreview: true`, I get no preview.

Tried:

```
await client.sendMessage(`${number}@c.us`, text, { linkPreview: { includePreview: true }});
```

or with:

```
await client.sendMessage(`${number}@c.us`, text);
```

none works.

[image]